# How to redirect a URL with old format using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I want to send a date parameter from homepage to a page (for example `/archives.html`) via `GET` method.

The clean URL of the link is:

```
127.0.0.1/archives.html/2014-5-17
```

So I have to redirect this to (for sending via `GET` method):

```
127.0.0.1/?option=com_archives&date=2014-5-17
```

by this htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ http://127.0.0.1/archives.html/?option=com_arcives&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The problem is that the beginning URL is a clean URL but the destination َURL is not.

**How can I have in source and destination a same clean URL and also send parameters to the destination?**

THE htaccess file:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#


RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1/?option=com_arcives&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA]


## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

- CMS - Joomla
- Web server - Apache
- PHP - Version 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `http://` from target URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1/?option=com_arcives&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for answer. source URL is 127.0.0.1/archives.html/2014-5-17 and after using this code, I can send parameters...but The clean-URL change to this: 127.0.0.1/?option=com_archives&date=2014-5-17
...I hope you underestand me...

Comment: That is strange since this rule doesn't change the URL. Can you post your complete .htaccess in question?

Comment: no it works. my link in homepage is:127.0.0.1/archives.html/2014-5-17...right? I put your code in htaccess...and when I click on 127.0.0.1/archives.html/2014-5-17 ... The address will change to 127.0.0.1/?option=com_archives&date=2014-5-17....right? it is ok...now I can send parameters to  archives.html page....but the URL of archives.html is ugly...because the URL of that page is: 127.0.0.1/?option=com_archives&date=2014-5-17

Comment: now...I want to know how can I keep The URL of destination clean-URL like 127.0.0.1/archives.html/2014-5-17

Comment: Yes thats what I wrote that since this rule doesn't have `R` flag it doesn't change the URL in browser (changes only internally). That might be due to some other rules (or try in a new browser to test).

Comment: I edited my question to put source code of my htaccess root file. unfortunatly your code do not work...but my code works.

Comment: I believe this will work: `RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1/?option=com_arcives&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R]` but will change the URL in browser. And that seems to be Joomla behavior which cannot work with internally rewritten URI.